# upgrade PowerShell assembly in C# project

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have an .Net3.5 application which has the reference of System.management.automation.dll from PowerShell2.0

[Microsoft says Powershell 2.0 will be deprecated](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/windows-powershell-2-0-deprecation/) :

Hosting Windows PowerShell 2.0 in a .NET 2.0/3.5 Application
If you’ve developed an application with .NET 2.0/3.5 (aka CLR2), and you’re hosting a PowerShell assembly like System.Management.Automation.dll, then you’re using the Windows PowerShell 2.0 version of those assemblies. If this is the case, you should work to migrate your application to .NET 4.6+ (aka CLR4) using reference assemblies from Windows PowerShell 3.0 or later. That way, you’ll be using the latest version of the Windows PowerShell assemblies available on the box. (Note: this may require that your Windows 7 or Server 2008 R2 users install .NET 4.6+ and/or WMF 3.0 or higher.)

So here are the questions:

1. So if I want to upgrade the PowerShell assembly to the newer version, I only need to recompile my appilcation in .NET4.6+?   If there no compiling errors and the compiled exe works well, does it means that I do not need to change source code?
2. And I found that I can add the Microsoft.PowerShell.5.ReferenceAssemblies by NuGet package, does this method have different behavior with adding the reference?
3. Is the exe reading the System.Management.Automation.dll library from the reference path while running, and if the machine that exe is running on does not has this library in the reference path that it will get errors?

Thanks in advance!